# Is there a newer version of gcc in red hat?

Tags: rhel, gcc, c++

I use Red Hat Enterprise in my school and I want to compile some c++11 code but the gcc --version is 4.4.7 which is not compatible.
Is that one the latest version in the red hat repositories?
is there any compiler that can be installed quickly using yum and that supports c++11?

Comment: `c++11` was standardized after the release of RHEL 6.

Comment: so there won't be any c++11 in RHEL 6?

Comment: It is probably possible to backport a package of gcc 4.7 to your system, but would require some effort. A local installation of gcc 4.7 is also possible, and would be easier.

Comment: Do you have administrator access on the system?

Comment: With RHEL7 Beta coming out I would highly doubt it! Backporting yourself will likely be your only option.

Comment: yes, I do have admin access @Mikel

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Clang seems to support [c++11](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

You can get Clang 3.0 from [ELrepo](http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/elrepo/extras/el6/x86_64/RPMS/) or Clang 3.4 from the [Clang/LLVM homepage](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html).

Comment: isn't it the same difficulty than trying to install some newer version of gcc?

Answer (score 2):

Supported way how to have more recent gcc is a special software collection with development tools called [Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/2/html-single/User_Guide/index.html). It contains GCC 4.8.1, which implements C++11 standard.